# C#- creating listview in wpf

Tags: wpf, listview

I am new to wpf and I want a to create a listview where the items of the listview is dynamically generated. Each of the items should contain  Textblocks images buttons and so on.Can anyone suggest how to go about it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding YourSource}"  >
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding YourPropery}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <ListView.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemsPanel>
 </ListView>
```

it's optional to define `ListView.ItemsPanel`.